# How to remove the section's title from the header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

In my header right now i have the title of the chapter and the title of the current section, I would like to remove the title of the section of the header and 
leavejust the chapter title

used packages

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn,longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{soul}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tableau}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

Comment: This depends on the used packages and classes. Please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050).

Comment: i just edit my question

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is not a full compilable code.

Comment: i just need to know to modify the text on the header

Comment: Please follow the link Skillmon gave you. As Bernard said, the code you provide should be compilable. It also should be minimal (without unnecessary parts not connected to the problem), as explained in that link.

Comment: Just a comment aside: your preamble loads several packages which conflict with each other (`sectsty` and `titlesec`, `titletoc` and `tocloft`)·

Answer (score 2):

In the following suggestion I will remove all the unrelated packages and code. Especially you can remove the line `\pagestyle{headings}` because it is overwritten by the later `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

For a onesided document you can remove the left header entry:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% option replaced

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Or you can declare the contents of the page header:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% option replaced

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{
  \fancyhead[R]{\slshape\leftmark}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]